# How to filter a graphene scalar field that is null in graphene-django?

Tags: django-filter, graphene-python, graphene-django

I have a `graphene.DateTime()` field as an argument in my graphene mutation. I can set filters on this field as described in the documentation like this:

```
class TaskNode(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = Task
        filter_fields = {
            "due_date": ["lte", "gte", "exact"],
        }
        interfaces = (relay.Node,)
```

These filters work just fine. I would like to, however, be able to filter those objects whose value of `due_date` is `null`. When I add `isnull` to the filters, however, I get the following.

Query:

```
query {
  allEvents(endDate_Isnull: true) {
    edges {
      node {
        id
      }
    } 
  }
}
```

Output:

```
"message": "Argument \"endDate_Isnull\" has invalid value true.
 Expected type \"DateTime\", found true.",
```

Apparently, even with `isnull` filter I can only enter a parameter value of type `DateTime`. What is the right way to implement this filter in graphene?

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine, but i suppose you encountered this bug: https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene-django/issues/750

Comment: That indeed seems to be the case. Thanks for pointing it out.